# laravel blade syntaxx not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, summernote, laravel-9

I'm using **laravel 9.** I have stored data using **summer note** in the database, but it shows empty or null when I retrieve data from the database.

**here is my code.**

```
{!! Str::of($item->product_description)->limit(40) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
{!! Str::limit($item->product_description,40) !!}
```

Comment: this is not working sir.